# Glide Image is not showing when using JSON but shows when using a static URL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am using @GET for retrieve data from JSON file. And i have recyclerview and data from the JSON is loaded into this recyclerview. The Recyclerview contains a ImageView, and 2 Textviews. Iam using GLIDE for viewing Image in the Recyclerview. But when I use static URL from the same JSON file the image is displayed. But when I change it nothing shows. Codes are given below.

AbiData.kt

```
data class AbiData(
val id: String,
val img_src: String,
val price: Int,
val type: String)
```

ApiInterface.kt

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("realestate")
fun getData(): Call<List<AbiData>>}
```

RecyclerAdapter.kt

```
class abiAdapter (val context: Context, val userList: List<AbiData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<abiAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder (itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val type : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type)
    val price : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price)
    val marsImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marsImage)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): abiAdapter.ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rows,parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: abiAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = userList[position]

    holder.type.text = currentItem.type
    holder.price.text = currentItem.price.toString()
    Glide.with(context).load(currentItem.img_src).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).into(holder.marsImage)


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}
```

}

On 'onBindViewHolder' in Recyclerview change the following line to below The image is showing correctly
**Glide.with(context).load("https://mars.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/01000/mcam/1000MR0044631300503690E01_DXXX.jpg").centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).into(holder.marsImage)**

But when change to
Glide.with(context).load(**currentItem.img_src**).into(holder.marsImage)
Image is not showing

In currentItem.img_src : The correct url is received.  I checked it with breakpoint.

[image]

The output is shown below

[image]

FragmentRecycler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".RecyclerFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/abiRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/rows"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#F4E6D7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/marsImage"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="164dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/marsImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.119"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/marsImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Logcat

```
2021-06-08 13:00:08.821 1390-1390/com.example.mars W/Glide: Load failed for http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/01000/mcam/1000MR0044631280503688E0B_DXXX.jpg with size [468x451]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
```

Comment: Why are you using ${} to access the path from the object? Ok I see you are using a string.

Use directly load(currentItem.img_src), your code looks good

Comment: Take a look at how to debug Glide issues from the [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html)

Comment: please monitor logs when glide fails it will be displayed in logs what wrong. thanks.

Comment: I Add Logcat in the question now. But I did'nt understand what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using simply using glide like this.

```
  Glide.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```

Dose it works with picasso?

**Post the xml also.**

make sure you are using latest version of glide.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Everyone who replys me. I findout the Issue.
I add following line in the Androidmanifest.xml file's  tag.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: You should not do this. It can lead to security threats.

Comment: Then what to do?

Comment: enable CleartextTraffic allows hhtp request for devices above version 9 . that was the reason.

Answer (score -1):

1. 1st check api is sending data correctly by using postman.
2. set adapter to recyclerview in api response or notifyitemchanged in onsuccess on your api method.
3. if api is sending data correctly then check whether image is accessible using the link which your api is sending back.

Comment: In userlist. Img_src : The correct image url is received. I check it with breakpoint.

Comment: can you share the url if possible because your image loading code is fine.

Comment: https://mars.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/01000/mcam/1000MR0044631300503690E01_DXXX.jpg